# Console.log not working on Reactjs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am doing a reactjs project but it there is a problem.  I am suppose to enter a text into the input the text is suppose to appear in the console.log.    Between onSubmit function between 42 to 52.  Everyone is saying that I need to add a key however I do not know where do had this key to the code to get the input box to render the text.  Any help you could give me would be appreciated.

https://github.com/lashleykeith/GoAndReactjs/tree/master/app
[Click here to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8ylB.jpg)

Here is the code
app.js

```
 let channels = [
    {name: 'Hardware Support'},
    {name: 'Software Support'}
 ];
 class Channel extends React.Component {
    onClick(){
        console.log('I was clicked', this.props.name);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
            )
    }
}

class ChannelList extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>
                {this.props.channels.map(channel => {
                    return (
                         <Channel name={channel.name} />
                        )
                    }
                )}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

class ChannelForm extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            channelName: e.target.value
        });
        //console.log(e.target.value);
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        let {channelName} = this.state;
        console.log(channelName);
        channels.push({
            name: channelName
        });
        this.setState({
            channelName: ''
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <input type='text'
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                    value={this.state.channelName}
                />
            </form>
            )
    }
}

class ChannelSection extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
        <div>
            <ChannelList channels={channels}/>
            <ChannelForm />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<ChannelSection />,
document.getElementById('app'));
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style type="text/css">
body, input {
font-size: 24px !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app" class="container-fluid">

</div>

<script type="text/babel" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did any of the answers below help?

Answer (score 2):

`form.onSubmit` gets called on `'submit'` event in form. To simulate this event, you need a button in your form that looks like

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit form label"/>
```

And on click on this button your `this.onSubmit.bind(this)` will get called.

There is an example in official React documentation that shows form usage and onSubmit event.

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Thanks for the input you have helped me to understand more.

Comment: solved my problem, added onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this) to my button and now I'm logging to console.  Score you.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that binding to this isn't being performed.  In other words 'this' of the form is different than 'this' of the component, hence no output.  Add this to your button `onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)`.  That's alotta thisses to explain how to print to console.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your binding of `this.onClick` inside a constructor method.

e.g.

```
class Channel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
...
}
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: Thank you it is working now I really appreciate your help.

Comment: No prob. Glad to! If this was the answer, marking it as correct is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

After you have inputed text you have to use the keyboard enter key or you should add a button of type submit inside your form if you want something visible to the user.